# Error of type PD: 15617 while using MongoDb

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, runtime-error, realm

Thought I would post an error I have been getting while using Mongodb. I get this error when I want to navigate to a screen that is connected to MongoDb but not sure why it happens.

Appreciate any feedback!

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.groundzero, PID: 15617
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.example.groundzero.mongodb.mongohomescreen.HomeViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(HomeViewModel.kt:27)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@43b8bcc, Dispatchers.Main]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [RLM_ERR_NO_SUCH_TABLE]: No such table exists
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.CoreErrorConverter.asThrowable(CoreErrorConverter.kt:42)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.realmcJNI.realm_get_class(Native Method)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.realmc.realm_get_class(realmc.java:558)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.RealmInterop.realm_get_class-nILuwFE(RealmInterop.kt:304)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.schema.CachedSchemaMetadata.<init>(CachedClassKeyMap.kt:101)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.LiveRealmReference.<init>(RealmReference.kt:108)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.ConfigurationImpl.openRealm$suspendImpl(ConfigurationImpl.kt:108)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.ConfigurationImpl.openRealm(Unknown Source:0)
at io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.internal.SyncConfigurationImpl.openRealm(SyncConfigurationImpl.kt:114)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl$1.invokeSuspend(RealmImpl.kt:107)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source:1)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.platform.CoroutineUtilsSharedJvmKt.runBlocking(CoroutineUtilsSharedJvm.kt:22)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.platform.CoroutineUtilsSharedJvmKt.runBlocking$default(CoroutineUtilsSharedJvm.kt:21)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl.<init>(RealmImpl.kt:106)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl$Companion.create$io_realm_kotlin_library(RealmImpl.kt:263)
at io.realm.kotlin.Realm$Companion.open(Realm.kt:82)
at com.example.groundzero.mongodb.data.MongoDB.configureTheRealm(MongoDB.kt:40)
at com.example.groundzero.mongodb.data.MongoDB.<clinit>(MongoDB.kt:26)
... 11 more
```

Comment: `[RLM_ERR_NO_SUCH_TABLE]: No such table exists`. What version of the drivers etc are you using?

Comment: Are you reffering to java version or sdk or?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the issue could be? @user20042973